# Which are the most accurate as possible lower and upper bounds for the $LCM$ of a given interval?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, least-common-multiple

I would like to define the most accurate as possible lower and upper bounds for $LCM([1..n])$, the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of a given interval $[1..n]$ (in old books is written as $[n]$).

Initially due to the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) I just can imagine these very simple options:

Lower bound:

> $$LCM([1..n]) \gt n\#$$

Where $n\#$ is the [primorial of $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial#Definition_for_natural_numbers), in other words, the product of the primes $p \le n$.

Upper bound:

> $$LCM([1..n]) \le n!$$

The factorial must be always greater or equal than the LCM of the interval. So summarizing:

> $$n\# \le LCM([1..n]) \le n!$$

They are easy to define, but they are not very accurate (closer to the value of the LCM).

> I would like to ask the following questions:
>
> 1. Are the proposed bounds correct?
> 2. Are there more accurate lower and upper bounds? Thank you!

Comment: An explicit formula for the lcm is $\prod_{p \le n} p^{\lfloor \log_p n\rfloor}$ with the product being taken over primes. You could then perhaps use the prime number theorem to estimate this above and below.

Comment: @T.Bongers thank you for the feedback! is that related with the second Chebishev function? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Relationships I already was aware of it, but I wondered if there is a way to calculate the bounds avoiding that "heavy" machinery.

Comment: The log of the product that I wrote is exactly $\sum_{p \le n} \lfloor \log_p n \rfloor \log p$, which is the second Chebyshev function. So my product is exactly $e^{\psi(x)}$.

Comment: @T.Bongers exactly! I am reading Ramanujan's proof of Bertrand's postulate, so when I was reading about that relationship the present question came into my mind. :) http://www.zyymat.com/ramanujans-proof-of-bertrands-postulate.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The power of $2$ that appears in the factorization of the least common multiple is the largest power of $2$ that is at most $n$. That is, $\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$. The power of $3$ that appears is similarly $\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor$, and so on. So the actual lcm is exactly equal to

$$\prod_{p \le n} p^{\lfloor \log_p n\rfloor} = \prod_{p \le n} p^{\lfloor \log n / \log p\rfloor}$$
where the products are taken over primes. This product is exactly $\exp \psi(x)$ where $\psi(x)$ is the [second Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function), for which lots of asymptotics are known.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation! I would like also to see other options avoiding the second Chebishev function, I need it for some lateral thinking! I will keep the question open for a while.